# Qt abstract class as interface

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on an IDE written in QT. I need to use the QMainWindow AND the QSyntaxHighLighter classes. However, when compiling it spits out the following error.

```
    cannot declare variable 'w' to be of abstract type 'SquareSDK'
```

That refers to my main.cpp file.

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        SquareSDK w;
        w.show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

That class is defined in ediot.h

```
    #ifndef EDIOT_H
    #define EDIOT_H

    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QFileDialog>
    #include <QtCore>
    #include <QtGui>
    #include <QObject>
    #include <QSyntaxHighlighter>

    namespace Ui {
    class SquareSDK;
    }

    class SquareSDK : public QMainWindow, private QSyntaxHighlighter
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit SquareSDK(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~SquareSDK();
    private slots:
        void on_actionUndo_triggered();

        void on_actionRedo_triggered();

        void on_actionCut_triggered();

        void on_actionCopy_triggered();

        void on_actionPaste_triggered();

        void on_actionNew_triggered();

        void on_actionOpen_triggered();

        void on_actionSave_triggered();

        void on_actionSave_As_triggered();

        void on_actionRun_in_Default_Web_Browser_triggered();

        void on_actionReload_triggered();

        void test();

        void syntax();

    private:
        Ui::SquareSDK *ui;
        QString mFilename;
        QString urlname;
        QString urldebug;
        QString OS;
        QString a;
        QString b;
        QString error;
        QString ext;
        QString text;
    };

    #endif // EDIOT_H
```

Comment: Read the docs on `QSyntaxHighlighter`, there's a pure virtual method that you need to provide an implementation for.  Since you have done that, your class is abstract.

Comment: I have tried in multiple ways, and I can't get it right. Which is kind of why I'm here.

Comment: Could you tell me how I would go about it?

Comment: Why do you use private inheritance? Can you just create another QSyntaxHighlighter subclass and use it inside mainWindow?

Comment: So, how would I do that? I am sorry for my excess of questions. This is the largest QT project I have ever worked on.

Comment: Check this example, http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html

Comment: That example isn't helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one or both of base classes have 1 or more **pure virtual** methods, **until** you **implement** them in `SquareSDK`, `SquareSDK` is an **abstract class** (because it **literally inherits** those pure virtual methods). **You can't instantiate an abstract class**.

*(Although you can use it as a type for pointer or reference. But it can only point to its non-abstract sub-classes, despite pointer-type being of abstract class. But that's not important right now)*

I checked out the documentation for `QSyntaxHighlighter`, and it has 1 **pure** virtual method.

```
//this is how it looks like inside QSyntaxHighlighter class
virtual void highlightBlock (const QString& text) = 0;
```

So implement it in your SquareSDK:

```
//in .h

void highlightBlock (const QString& text);

//in .cpp

void SquareSDK::highlightBlock (const QString& text)
{
    //...yourcode... 
}
```

It's a function for highlighting blocks, and because it's pure virtual, it has **absolutely no original behavior defined** so you must program it **completely on your own**. So implement it in a way it **highlights a block** the way you want it highlighted.

`QMainWindow`, luckily, contains no **pure** virtual methods, which cuts you some slack.

EDIT:
Inherit QSyntaxHighlighter as public. `highlightBlock` is protected, and if base class is inherited as private, it becomes unreachable.

Comment: now it says no matching function for call to 'QSyntaxHighlighter::QSyntaxHighlighter()' pointing to ediot.cpp line 6 and expected primary-expression before const line 10

        SquareSDK::SquareSDK(QWidget *parent) :
            QMainWindow(parent),
            ui(new Ui::SquareSDK)
        {
            ui->setupUi(this);
            test();
            highlightBlock (const QString& text);
        }

<-- those are lines 4-11

Comment: Inherit QSyntaxHighlighter as public. highlightBlock is protected, and if base class is inherited as private, it becomes unreachable. If problem persists or there is another one, give us ediot.cpp. It says the problem is there, so I think you're likely to have multiple errors.

Comment: You need to call QSyntaxHighlighter constructor on SquareSDK constructor. SquareSDK::SquareSDK(QWidget *parent) : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent) QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::SquareSDK). As you're not mentioning it, the compuler assumes QSyntaxHighlighter(), which doesn't exist. You can find the constructors here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html.

Comment: Thank you cruelcore1! However, now it says "expected primary-expression before 'const'" ediot.cpp line 11

Comment: Cppy paste the line here

Comment: "'Q_OBJECT' is an ambiguous base of 'SuareSDK'"

Answer (score 2):

Double `QObject` inheritance is forbidden in `Qt`! So you can't do it with `QMainWindow` and  `QSyntaxHighlighter`. In this case double inheritance is bad in many many other ways!

Use composition not aggregation here!

Comment: Then how would I do this?

Comment: [check out example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html)